# How to recreate the animation in the Notes iPad app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

When you use the Notes iPad app (from Apple) in landscape mode, you see the list of notes to the left. If you select a note you see a nice little animation that looks like someone is marking the note with a red pencil.

I already have a graphic that looks like that red circle, but how do I animate it like that? Thank you in advance.

**Edit 1**
Here is a link to the graphic: [red circle](http://www.iosdevelopers.nl/images/redcircle.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't actually know the animation you're talking about, but assuming I understand what it does, then one simple way is to use the built in `UIImageView` support for displaying a series of images as an animation. You then need a separate image for each frame.

```
NSArray* imageFrames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame1.png"],
                                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame2.png"],
                                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame3.png"],
                                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame4.png"],
                                                 nil];
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
[imageView setAnimationImages:imageFrames];
[imageView setAnimationDuration:10];
[imageView setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
```

The above creates a `UIImageView` with 4 frames that animate over 10 seconds. The animation repeats 3 times.

See the [`UIImageView` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Obviously then you actually need a series of images to animate.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)moveRedCircle {
    UIImageView *redcircle = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"redcircle.png"]];
    redcircle.bounds.origin = CGPointMake(x, y);
    [self.view addSubview:redcircle];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4 animations:^{
        redcircle.bounds.origin = CGPointMake(x, y);
    }];
}
```

Replace the first x and y with where you want the circle to be initially.
Replace the last x and y with the origin of where you want it to move.

Comment: No I don't mean moving the red circle, the animation is a bit more complex than that. It really looks like the red circle is being drawn.

Comment: Can I see your graphic please?